# Android support repository path for manual copy

Tags: android, android-studio

Due to internet speed problems, android studio had problem downloading the file
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip

I download the file manually, now where should I copy (or extract) this file?

Comment: You want to wind up with an `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository` directory, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is wherever you have the Android SDK installed. However, you would need to examine that ZIP file to see what the directory structure is inside of it, to determine what directories you need to create, where you should unZIP the file, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your android sdk installation there is a folder called extras

android-sdk\extras

inside extras extract your zip files android_m2repository_r41.zip and support_r23.2.1.zip and then rename these folders to
m2repository and support

at the end it should look like 
android-sdk\extras\m2repository 
and
android-sdk\extras\support